# Data sent through post method results in a null object

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, null, odata

this is my first time ever asking a question on stackoverflow. I have searched through this site many times to look for answers, but this is my first time asking my own! Hopefully I will give enough information so you guys can understand my question.

So basically I have created a new table in our database on sqlserver. I have created a new entity in our entity framework to map to this table as well. The problem is my post method in my odata controller for this database table. Here is the method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("TerminalPersonnelEmails/LoadEmail()")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(TerminalPersonnelEmail))]        
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync(TerminalPersonnelEmail email)
    {
        if (email == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The data entry given is invalid");
        }

        portalDatabaseContext.TerminalPersonnelEmails.Add(email);
        await portalDatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return Created(email);
        return Ok("test"); //will be replaced once post method is fixed
    }
```

Here is what I am sending through postman:

```
  {"TerminalEmail" :{
"Id" : 1,
"Name" : "NewEmail",
"Email" : "email@email.com",
"TerminalNumber" : 23084093284 } }
```

(Sorry for weird indentations/placement of brackets. When i pasted in the code, 1 or 2 indentations were off and my postman code was messed up so I fixed it as best as I could to get it into the code block box).

I have tried several ways to send this data. I have tried just sending the data without clumping it into "TerminalEmail", not sending Id because it is autonum in the database, and I have messed with the content type (json, text, etc.). None of this has worked.

I have made sure that the data matches up with the object so that it should be passing in a valid object to the c# method, but it still is null. I have tired out all of my options and need your help. Thanks!

edit: Here is declaration of terminalpersonnelemail class in the entityframework as requested:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Marketing.EntityFramework.Portal
{
    [Table("TerminalPersonnelEmails", Schema = "Portal")]
    public class TerminalPersonnelEmail
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TerminalNumber { get; set; }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `TerminalPersonnelEmail` class declaration?

Comment: Is there `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>`
in your Web.config?

Comment: I just added the class declaration in my post for you!

Comment: In web.config, it currently has <httpruntime targetFramework="4.5" />

Comment: "TerminalNumber" : 23084093284 may cause an overflow here? May be not related with the problem, but still this number seems to be bigger than the int.Max??

Comment: It is not the answer to the problem, but thanks Deniz! This is something I didn't notice that probably would've caused another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out how to fix it, but I couldn't tell you why this works. I took out the odata route, and in my odata config took out everything except the entityset that I had created. Here is the working code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(TerminalPersonnelEmail))]        
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(TerminalPersonnelEmail email)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (email == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The data entry given is invalid");
            }


            portalDatabaseContext.TerminalPersonnelEmails.Add(email);
            await portalDatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(email);
```